# Loop for data structure conversion

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with conversion from one data structure to another. 
I've got this:

```
var obiekat={
            "drogi" : [
                {
                "miasta" : ["A", "B"],
                "czas_przejazdu" : 3
                },
                {
                "miasta" : ["A", "C"],
                "czas_przejazdu" : 2
                }
            ],
            "max_czas_przejazdu" :4
            };
```

I want to convert it to object built like this:

```
 var nodes_fire ={
                "A" : 
                {    
                    "B":3 ,
                    "C":2

                },
                "B" :
                {
                    "A":3           
                },
                "C" :
                {
                    "A":2           
                }
            };
```

I need to convert it despite the number of roads. I don't know how to start building such function. I've tried a lot of things- probably wrong.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button>Click</button>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('button').click(function(){
       var obiekat={
            "miasta" : [
                 {
                 "nazwa" : "A",
                 "ma_jednostke" : true
                 },
                 {
                 "nazwa" : "B",
                 "ma_jednostke" : true
                 }
            ],
            "drogi" : [
                {
                "miasta" : ["A", "B"],
                "czas_przejazdu" : 3
                },
                {
                "miasta" : ["A", "C"],
                "czas_przejazdu" : 2
                }
            ],
            "max_czas_przejazdu" :4
            };

var nodes_fire = 
            {
                "A" : 
                {    
                    "B":1 ,
                    "C":3

                },
                "B" :
                {
                    "A":2           
                },
                "C" :
                {
                    "A":3           
                }
            };
        var rnowy=[];
        var nowy={};
        var second_city,first_city,travel;

        var ritem={};
        var item={};
        var summer1=[],
            summer2=[];


        for ( property in obiekat.drogi ){
            var count = 0;

            first_city=obiekat.drogi[property].miasta[0];       
            second_city=obiekat.drogi[property].miasta[1];      
            travel=obiekat.drogi[property].czas_przejazdu;      
            ritem[second_city]=obiekat.drogi[property].czas_przejazdu;

            if(item.hasOwnProperty(first_city)){
               item[first_city]=ritem;
            }else{
               item[first_city]=ritem;
            }

            rnowy.push(item);
            count++;
        }
       $('#result').text(JSON.stringify(rnowy));

  });
});
  </script>

<pre id="result">
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [There is no JSON in the question](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] before we can help you debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` to build object but you will need two `forEach()` loops inside first to loop cities and then another time to find others in same array but not the one from outer loop.

```js
var object = {
  "roads": [{
    "cities": ["A", "B"],
    "time": 3
  }, {
    "cities": ["A", "C"],
    "time": 2
  }]
};

var result = object.roads.reduce(function(r, e) {
  e.cities.forEach(function(c) {
    if(!r[c]) r[c] = {}
    e.cities.forEach(function(n) {
      if(n != c) Object.assign(r[c], {[n]: e.time})
    })
  })
  return r
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm ! I didn't think that it's possible to make it in 10 lines of code :O